# Is it possible to perform a *discrete* geometric sum without for-loops?

Tags: c, algorithm, int

### The problem

Mind the following problem: a wizard can create and destroy runes. Creating a new rune costs an amount of mana proportional to the number of runes previously created. Destroying a rune recovers the mana used to create it. Below, I present a possible implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned long int uint64;

typedef struct WizardT {
  uint64 runes;
  uint64 mana;
  uint64 cost;   // mana cost for creating a new rune
  uint64 reward; // mana reward for destroying a rune
} Wizard;

// Creates a number of runes
void create(Wizard *wiz, uint64 amount){
  uint64 i;
  for (i=0; i<amount; ++i){
    wiz->runes += 1;
    wiz->mana -= wiz->cost; // creating a rune has a cost
    wiz->cost = wiz->cost * 1025 / 1024; // each rune created increases the cost of creating another cake
    wiz->reward = wiz->reward * 1025 / 1024; // read below
  };
}

// Destroy a number of runes
void destroy(Wizard *wiz, uint64 amount){
  uint64 i;
  for (i=0; i<amount; ++i){
    wiz->runes -= 1;
    wiz->mana += wiz->reward; // each rune we destroy give us back the mana required to create it
    wiz->cost = (wiz->cost * 1024 + 1024) / 1025;
    wiz->reward = (wiz->reward * 1024 + 1024) / 1025;
  };
}

void print(Wizard* wiz){
  printf("runes %lu, mana %lu, cost %lu, reward %lu",
        wiz->runes, wiz->mana, wiz->cost, wiz->reward);
}

int main(){
  Wizard wiz;
  wiz.runes = 0;
  wiz.mana = 1000000;
  wiz.cost = 1025;
  wiz.reward = 1024;

  create(&wiz, 10);
  destroy(&wiz, 10);
  print(&wiz);
};
```

Here, there are functions to `create` and `destroy` N runes, with each new rune costing `1025\1024` more mana than the previous. Note that it is a zero-sum problem, so `create(wiz, N); destroy(wiz, N)` always leaves `wiz` unchanged.

### Getting rid of the loop with geometric sums

This problem is very similar to the geometric sum, since the required mana to create N runes is `k + k * r^1 + k * r^2 + k * r^3 ... k * r^N`, with `r = 1025/1024`. As such, one would wonder if those `for-loops` could be replaced by a constant-time formula. Issue is, the `destroy` for-poop must be aware of the integer-division floorings performed by `create`, using a ceil inter division, otherwise it reward give more/less mana than it should. The geometric sums formula isn't aware of that, so it has rounding issues.

### The question

Is there any way to implement `create` and `destroy` without a loop, such that `create(wiz, N); destroy(wiz, N)` leaves the `wiz` unchanged, for any positive integer `N`?

Comment: In the abstract, it seems like there should be a scalable lookup to handle these cases. Is there a upper limit on the mana / number of runes that can be created in the WORLD? Not each wizard, but rather some sort of speed of light max? If not, I am not sure you can create a closed form (loopless) calculation. I can't promise that if you do have a limit a useful closed form exists, though. Also, does the cost vary per wizard? If so, how? Some fixed constant at, say, creation, or is it variable (based on condition/health/sleep/etc/level based attibutes)?

Comment: I don't think it's useful trying to maintain the same rounding behavior compared with your for-loop solution, but it's more important to try to maintain associativity and commutativity.

Comment: Can you store the attributes as real numbers and just display them as integers? Computing a lookup-table as proposed by @Kristian is probably a good idea. Just store the prefix sum of the i-th rune creation and you can get the sum of any range by two lookups.

Comment: Instead of factors (such as 1025/1024) I'd precalculate for each Wizard type a vector with the integer increments of the cost of the next rune. That would make formulas easier and without roundings issues.

Comment: All I need is a solution to the problem using only machine ints since this will run in a virtual machine (Ethereum's EVM) which has only int operations. There is nothing else to this problem, no varying rates etc., what I stated is the entire game logic: you can pay/get mana to create/destroy runes **of a kind**; the more runes of a specific kind exist, the more expensive creating new ones is. The idea is that you'll create a ton of runes of a kind that you think is undervalued, so when people buy more of it, you can destroy the ones you purchased, getting more total mana than you started.

Comment: So, in short, that is all I need, a way to compute the cost of N runes and the reward of N runes given a K amount of already created runes, using integers, while avoiding rounding errors that would destroy the zero-sum characteristics and allow for exploits.

Comment: if you only care about balancing mama, then in your destroy function, instead of calculating the reward of destroying N-M to N runes, calculate the new cost of 0 to N-M-1 runes, then subtract it from current sum of cost, the add that to the reward.

Comment: wiz->cost = (wiz->cost * 1024 + 1024) / 1025 can be rewritten wiz->cost=((++wiz->cost) << 10) / 1025

Comment: wiz->cost * 1025 / 1024 can be rewritten (wiz->cost * (1024+1)) / 1024 =>  (wiz->cost * 1024+ wiz->cost) / 1024 => (++wiz->cost <<10 ) >> 10.

Comment: on the other side, this kind of recursive formula can be written shortly using generating functions.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to implement `create` and
>   `destroy` without a loop, such that `create(wiz, N);
>   destroy(wiz, N)` leaves the `wiz` unchanged, for any
>   positive integer `N`?
>
> All I need is a solution to the problem using only machine ints

There is definitely no way, because for a certain `N` the computation will overflow an `int`, so it can't be calculated at all (not even with a loop). To make the question sensible, give a limit for `N`.